# Measuring scale in millimeters for measuring distances in MeshLab 64 bit 02/2022 edition

Tags: asp.net

I need to know if the distanc between two points in 3d face scan is calculated in millimeters or I need a specifice scale to measure it .

I need to measure between two points in millimeters so I can compare the results with related dicom file measuements

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.